# Do MySQL Connections close automatically when the program exits?

Tags: java, mysql, database

If I create a MySQL Connection in my java program, and the program exits from main method, what happens to this MySQL Connection?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Connection conn = getConnection(...);

    return;    
}
```

Does this connection get closed automatically?

Or does the connection stays alive until it times out?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516423/will-the-sql-connections-automatically-get-closed-if-we-close-the-jvm

Answer (score 1):

The operating system will either close or reset all open TCP connections of a process when the process exits, depending on the platform. In either event the database server will notice immediately. No timeout.

Comment: No, although the OS would clean up client-side resources *immediately* it doesn't happen so at the backend. For e.g, in Oracle when a user process with direct connection fails, the PMON "process monitor" db process performs database-side recovery. But, it's not instantaneous; it has some delay which under heavy db traffic would break and throw "too many open connections" error.

Comment: I stand by my remarks. If that's how it's works it is poorly programmed. There is no necessity for any delay.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a resource leak right there. The `Connection` object would cease to exist because the JVM just terminates when your `main()` ends, but the resources allocated on the database server would stay open for a while till the database decides to reclaim them after a *timeout*.

This is a very bad practice because if a program terminates without explicitly closing its database `Connection`, what happens to all the database operations (like insert, updates etc.) done before, is *undefined*. Some, JDBC drivers would ***commit*** your changes and some would do an implicit ***rollback***.

It is highly recommended to not depend on such *undefined* database specific behaviour because then you're giving up the benefits of using a database agnostic JDBC API and compromise your application's portability for no gains in return.